# Contact Duplicate error not fired while upserting duplicate Contacts in bulk in apex

Tags: apex, batch, schedulebatch

We have a Duplicate Rule defined on Contact Object.

The requirement is to insert or update Contact records in Batch apex. Ideally, if any duplicate is found I should get Duplicate Error in apex.

While implementing this use case, I have seen a weird behavior that when execute method is called for 1st set of Contacts, I am able to insert duplicate contacts with no errors, ideally it should error out and when execute method is called for 2nd set of Contacts then I am seeing duplicate contact error if any duplicate is found.

Why would apex not show Duplicate Error while inserting Duplicate contacts?

When I try from UI, I get proper Duplicate error message.

Any Help?

Comment: Does this help? https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000e3ggQAA

Comment: Ohh, yea it did help, Thank you so much. But just wondering why would salesforce do that? It should fire even in case of bulk insert also right?

Comment: Ideally, it should, but I honestly don't know why Salesforce chose to have it this way and couldn't find much documentation on the same.

Comment: Got you... Appreciate your help..!! Thank you..!!